# Как сравнить 2 картинки попиксельно?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть 2 картинки и мне нужно их сравнить попиксельно, что бы каждый совпадающий пиксель красился в серый, а не совпадающий в красный(желательно что бы можно было подсчитать к-во красных пикселей
node js

Comment: https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/wiki/Matrix, https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixelmatch

Comment: спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @XelaNimed, а как мне игнорить прозрачность(альфа канал) если он есть на одной из картинок? 
P.S. использую pixelmatch

Comment: Не знаком с библиотекой, но судя по описанию в readme на github, за это отвечает опция includeAA, хотя конечно могу ошибаться.